# Error handling graphql in Elm (0.18)

Tags: graphql, elm

I'm trying to use graphql with Elm 0.18.  The libraries I have found online don't seem to work with 0.18, so I'm rolling my own.

Let's say I have a nested query.  The function that makes the query and http call looks something like this:

```
import Http
import HttpBuilder exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Encode as Encode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Pipeline as Pipeline exposing (decode, required)

fetchPosts : Model -> Cmd Msg
fetchPosts model =
  let
    graphiql =
      """
        query {
          postById(id: 1) {
            id
            author {
              id
              name
            }
            content
            comments {
              date 
              author {
                id
                name
              }
              content
            }
          }
        }
      """

    localUserDecoder = 
      Pipeline.decode User
        |> Pipeline.required "id" Decode.int
        |> Pipeline.required "name" Decode.string

    localCommentDecoder =
      Pipeline.decode Comment
        |> Pipeline.required "date" Decode.string
        |> Pipeline.required "author" localUserDecoder
        |> Pipeline.required "string" Decode.string

    localPostDecoder =
      Pipeline.decode Post
        |> Pipeline.required "id" Decode.int
        |> Pipeline.required "author" localUserDecoder
        |> Pipeline.required "content" Decode.string
        |> Pipeline.required "comments" (Decode.list localCommentDecoder)

    localDecoder =
        Decode.at [ "data", "postById" ] <|
            localPostDecoder
  in
      HttpBuilder.post ("http://myserver/api")
          |> HttpBuilder.withStringBody "text/plain" graphiql
          |> HttpBuilder.withExpect (Http.expectJson localDecoder)
          |> HttpBuilder.send GetPostCompleted
```

When it goes through, and passes along the returned `Post` type to `GetPostCompleted`, all is well.  But suppose something is off.  I mislabel `author` as `user` somewhere, or fields are out of order in the decoder.  The compiler will not tell me where I made the error, instead I will just see a correct query in the Network table, but a non-descript error thrown from my elm code.

Is there any way to structure this so that, if there is something wrong with one of the decoders, I can see an error thrown to the console or something?  Currently I have to unpack the whole thing and put it together piece by piece, which is very difficult and un-elm-like.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you are correct about the graphql libraries not supporting 0.18.

The bigger question is why it is not possible to go from a typed elm data structure to a (effectively) typed graphql request, and the corresponding Decoders. But that of course requires analysis of types, which sounds a level above what the compiler aims to do. (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sh4H8yzXnvw for how this can be done in Haskell using Generics)

As a result, even the existing libraries require more boiler plate than you would hope for. I don't see a way around this.

You could build the request more directly if you could iterate of the fields of an Elm record type, but even with that you could not get to automatically generated decoders ... I think.

What I am not sure is whether you could parse the graphql json definitions and derive elm decoders from that

Comment: I'm still new to Elm, but I have heard complaints about the Type system.  Is this the main thing that people are complaining about?

Comment: No, the complaints - such as they are - are about type classes, and boil down to extra boiler-plate. It would need a much more advanced type system here I think (think Haskell or beyond)